# Переменные angular

Tags: angular

У меня есть переменная, которая содержит адрес для апи, внутри сервиса.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в девелопе у меня она была одной, а в продакшене, после билда другой?

Comment: [вы читали документацию?](https://angular.io/guide/build)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно.

У вас в проекте должна быть папка `environments` с файлами `environment.ts` и `environment.prod.ts`. Если их нет - создайте.

В них (файлах) должен быть одинаковый набор переменных с одинаковыми или разными значениями. В зависимости от типа сборки будут подставляться нужные значения. Вот пример содержимого файлов:

`environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiPath: '/myApiPath'
};
```

`environment.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiPath: '/myApiPathForDev'
};
```

После создания этих файлов можно получить в коде доступ к переменным так:

1. Импортируем переменные:

   ```
   import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
   ```
2. Используем:

   ```
   console.log(environment.apiPath);
   ```

Работает это так: в файле `angular.json` указаны все ваши конфигурации сборки и в них указывается надо ли заменять к-л файлы при сборке и, если надо, то на какие. Выглядит так:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              ...
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "test": {
              ...
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
        ...
```